# Python list comprehension - Directly returning large list is faster than storing, then returning

Tags: python, performance, return, list-comprehension

I was working on a problem recently that required me to go through a very large folder (~600,000 files) and return the list of filenames that matched a certain criterion. The original version was a normal list comprehension stored in a variable. This isn't the actual code but it gives the gist.

```
    def filter_files(file_path):
      filtered = [f.path for f in os.scandir(file_path) if f.path.endswith('.png')]
      return filtered
```

When monitoring this one it would start out fast then progressively get slower and slower. I presume because it's just trying to store so much data in the variable.

I then rewrote it to be:

```
    def filter_files(file_path):
      return [f.path for f in os.scandir(file_path) if f.path.endswith('.png')]
```

And called it like:

```
    def test(file_path):
      filtered = filter_files(file_path)
```

This one never slows down. It maintains the same speed the entire time.

My question is what under the hood causes this difference? The data is still being stored in a variable and it's still being processed as a list comprehension. What about writing the comprehension in a return avoids the issues of the first version? Thanks!

Comment: There is no difference between those two pieces of code.  None at all.  Both of them are creating a list, and then managing a reference to that list.  There must have been something else going on in your code.

Comment: I'm assuming this has something to do some files already existing in your machine's disk cache, not anything to do with your Python code.

Comment: What do you mean it will "start out fast"? How can you tell this?

Comment: @Cruncher I used tqdm to monitor the estimated time and number of iterations per second.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarification, I thought it seemed weird that they'd behave differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between those two pieces of code.  None at all.  Both of them are creating a list, and then managing a reference to that list.

The likely cause of your issue is caching.  In the first case, the file system has to keep going out to the disk over and over and over to fetch more entries.  After you finished that, the directory was in the file cache and could be read immediately.  Reboot and try again, and you'll see the second one takes the same amount of time.

Comment: You can also use the `dis` module to verify that both function definitions generate identical byte code. The unnecessary assignment gets optimized away.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Ah that makes sense. I want to say that I had directly tried switching back and forth between the two and there was still a noticeable difference but it's possible that I only ran the first one before the second. Thanks for your answer